# How to extract unix timestamp and get date

Tags: go

I have an integer

```
x := 1468540800
```

I want to fetch the date out of this unix timestamp in Golang. I have tried `time.ParseDuration` but looks like that's not the correct way to extract date out of this. Converstion should happen like this http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php
I intend to convert into in ISO 8601 format may be. I want string like `2016-09-14`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `t := time.Unix(int64(x), 0)` with location set to local time.
Or use `t := time.Unix(int64(x), 0).UTC()` with the location set to UTC.

You may use `t.Format("2006-01-02")` to format,
Code (try on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Br4S-JlE1Z)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    x := 1468540800
    t := time.Unix(int64(x), 0).UTC() //UTC returns t with the location set to UTC.
    fmt.Println(t.Format("2006-01-02"))
}
```

output:

```
2016-07-15
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`time.Unix`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Unix) with nanoseconds set to 0.

```
t := time.Unix(int64(x), 0)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/PpOv8Xm-CS.

Comment: Thanks I tried this and I noticed that 1468540800 results into `2016-07-14 19:00:00 -0500 CDT` while if I try to verify at http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php it shows me date as 2016-07-15 any reason why?

Comment: @love2code time zones. The "-0500" you got should be a pretty good hint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use strconv.ParseInt() for parsing to int64 in combination with time.Unix.

```
myTime,errOr := strconv.ParseInt(x, 10, 64)
    if errOr != nil {
        panic(errOr)
    }
    newTime := time.Unix(myTime, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this and I noticed that 1468540800 results into `2016-07-14 19:00:00 -0500 CDT` while if I try to verify at http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php it shows me date as 2016-07-15 any reason why?

Comment: @love2code Print out the time as UTC insted of your local timezone. e.g. `fmt.Println(newtime.UTC())`

Answer (score -4):

```
$timestamp=1468540800;
echo gmdate("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```